# how to search through a column of links looking for string matches in r?

Tags: r, paste, grepl

I have a data table with a list of .txt links in the same column.  I am looking for a way for R to search within each link to see if the file contains either of the strings *discount rate* or *discounted cash flow*.  I then want R to create 2 columns next to each link (one for *discount rate* and one for *discounted cash flow*) that is either going to have a 1 in it if present or a 0 if not.

[image: current table with links in column websiteURL]

[image: what i want my table to look like]

Here's a small list of sample links that I would like to sift through:

```
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1015328/0000913849-04-000510.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1460306/0001460306-09-000001.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1063761/0001047469-04-028294.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1230588/0001178913-09-000260.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288246/0001193125-04-155851.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1436866/0001172661-09-000349.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1089044/0001047469-04-026535.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1274057/0001047469-04-023386.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1300379/0001047469-04-026642.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1402440/0001225208-09-007496.txt
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/35527/0001193125-04-161618.txt
```

Comment: `dput()` > imgs

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this...

```
checktext <- function(file, text) {
  filecontents <- readLines(file)
  return(as.numeric(any(grepl(text, filecontents, ignore.case = TRUE))))
}

df$DR <- sapply(df$file_name, checktext, "discount rate")
df$DCF <- sapply(df$file_name, checktext, "discounted cash flow")
```

A much faster version, thanks to Gregor's comment below, would be

```
checktext <- function(file, text) {
  filecontents <- readLines(file)
  sapply(text, function(x) as.numeric(any(grepl(x, filecontents, 
               ignore.case = T))))
}

df[,c("DR","DCF")] <- t(sapply(df$file_name, checktext, 
                             c("discount rate", "discounted cash flow")))
```

Or if you are doing it from URLs rather than local files, replace `df$file_name` with `df$websiteURL` in the above.  It worked for me on the short list you provided.

Comment: Connecting and reading the file will be quite slow, but grep will be fast. It would be *much* more efficient to use read each file once and use `grep` on it twice. Let `text` be a vector in your `checktext` function and use something like `sapply(text, function(x) as.numeric(any(grepl(x, filecontents, ignore.case = T))))`

Comment: @Gregor Yes - that would be much faster - many thanks.  I've added it to the main answer.